# Using same VBA code in English and German Excel - Expected Function Or Variable

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I've created a vba code in the English version of Excel 2016 for Windows.
I've attempted to run the code in a German version of Excel 2011 and 2016 for Mac but both do not work.

I'm getting an error that the **sub function is waiting for a variable or function**.

Trying to debug what the real problem, it seems there are three issues:

1. `IFNA()` is not a available function in Excel for Mac - so I had it removed.
2. I'm using `INDEX`, `MATCH` functions. `MATCH` is translated into *VERGLEICH* in German Excel and so the function is not recognized.
3. This line of code is also causing problems, seems like `Range().Activate` or `Range().Select` is also not recognized.

   `x = Range("A" & insert_at).Activate`

Any ideas or guidance in the last two issues would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: As long as you are using `.Formula = "=INDEX(...,MATCH(...))"` it must work since `Formula` is always using EN_US locale. Don't use `FormulaLocal`. And what do you expect to be `x` after `x = Range("A" & insert_at).Activate`? `Activate` returns either `True` or `FALSE`.

Comment: Is the international separator "," or "." in germany?  That causes nightmares for me in france.  I'd also look at your date formats, but other than that there shouldnt be too many differences

Comment: @tompreston, try this `?Application.DecimalSeparator`

Comment: @Vityata Thanks, I use  if Application.DecimalSeparator = "," then ...replace",", "." in general, I don't suppose you've come across a way to do this for a whole book (and specifically for numbers), rather thank specific ranges?

Comment: Well, I do not have this problem, because I use `Formula` and not `Formula.Local`. Thus, the Excel takes care of the separators.

Comment: Thanks for your help! There IFNA function is not supported in Excel for Mac. The other part was the: `x = Range("A" & insert_at).Activate` which was not recognized, I removed the `x=` part and the macro now works for both operating systems.

Comment: @tompreston what do you mean international separator ? for function objects or digits? For functions its ";" , for digits its "."

Answer (score 0):

And 6 months later I was googling a problem in StackOverflow to which I gave a useful comment. Its like getting help from yourself in the past:)

In general:

`Application.DecimalSeparator`

would save you, if you are concatenating a string formula in non-English Excel VBA.

---

`Selection.Formula` would return the formula in English:

`=VLOOKUP("Something",[VIT.xlsx]Monatsbericht!C2:C5,2,0)`

---

`Selection.FormulaLocal` would return the formula in the local Excel language (German in this case):

`=SVERWEIS("Something";[VIT.xlsx]Monatsbericht!C2:C5;2;0)`

---

`Selection.FormulaR1C1` would return the formula in R1C1 format, in English:

```
=VLOOKUP("Something",[UHL.xlsx]Monatsbericht!R[-15]C[-1]:R[-12]C[-1],2,0)
```

---

`Selection.FormulaR1C1Local` would return the formula in R1C1 format, in the local language:

```
=SVERWEIS("Something";[UHL.xlsx]Monatsbericht!Z(-15)S(-1):Z(-12)S(-1);2;0)
```

---